# MongoDB-Style Array Aggregate in Postgres

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to translate a MongoDB aggregate query to Postgres. My schema has an array of strings called `array_one`, a date field `updated`, and a `cluster` field that identifies which documents are clustered together (i.e. share a cluster ID).

What I need to do is find the most popular `cluster` values of documents that pass a filter (`array_one` containing a value, `updated` between a time, etc).

This is my MongoDB aggregate pipeline:

```
var query = [
      { $match: { array_one: 'INCLUDE_VAL', updated: { $gt: new Date(Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * trendingDurationHours)), $lt: new Date() } } },
      { $group: {_id: '$cluster', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
      { $sort: { count: -1 } },
      { $limit: 10 }
];
```

Any idea how to do this in Postgres?

Comment: By using [count](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/) ?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. I didn't know you could use `count` for that. Thanks -- if you make that an answer, I'll accept it.